# TFS 2010 Custom Build Workflow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, workflow, workflow-foundation

I am a PHP programmer, i usually don't work in Visual Studio especially not with Team Foundation Server, but my current job requires me to use it.

My problem is that i need to create a custom build workflow (.xaml file) that will copy (ideally zip) my latest sources from dev version (source control in TFS) of a project to a network share (\myserver\myshare\myproject) when i hit the Queue new build.

I tried through the visual editor bit i didn't have any positive results (all i have figured was how to make a variable), i tried to edit the .xaml file by hand (text editor) but it didn't get me very far...

It doesn't need to understand solutions or projects, it only needs to copy the files from the projects folder in TFS source control to a network share....

I need a step by step, click by click guide how to do it,
Thanks in advance

Software used: Visual Studio 2010 Pro, Team Foundation Server 2010, VS.PHP 2.10.3

Comment: Removed PHP tag as the question isn't _about_ PHP, and added workflow-foundation, which the question is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In visual studio 2010, use View > Toolbox to see all activities, and then drag and drop them. Some of them also have Properties to setup.

Comment: Any idea why my custom activity won't "drop"? I get the no sign (circle with diagonal slash)

Answer (score 2):

To do the copying, add a [`CopyDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg419654.aspx) activity after the `SyncWorkspace` activity (which is named "Get Workspace" and is located in Process / Sequence / Run On Agent / Initialize Workspace), then set the [Source property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.copydirectory.source.aspx) to `SourcesDirectory` and the [Destination property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.copydirectory.destination.aspx) to your network share, or a variable with that value if you prefer.

To zip the files up, you will probably want to use an `InvokeProcess` activity, calling some kind of script and passing the SourcesDirectory variable in: as an example, this is how to [zip files with powershell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/daiken/archive/2007/02/12/compress-files-with-windows-powershell-then-package-a-windows-vista-sidebar-gadget.aspx).

Edit:

To execute a batch file, grab an InvokeProcess activity from the Visual Studio Toolbox, specifically the Team Foundation Build Activities tab, and drop it onto the workflow. Click the activity, press F4 to see the properties window, and fill in the path to your batch file and any arguments you want to pass to it. Follow [these instructions](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/10/01/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-11-Speed-up-opening-my-build-process-template.aspx) if the activities don't appear in your toolbox.

Comment: hi, i am sure this would be very useful post if i knew what you are talking about.., i worked in visual studio 2010 for the first time today.., can i somehow execute a batch script on the TFS ? what is the simplest was ? Where to click to add activity ? i need click by click guide....

Answer (score 1):

Easy option is to just run with the standard build template and configure the build definition with the required UNC path for the drop folder. This will push all the source from the workspace out to that location when the build completes. You can then manually zip it yourself. If you want to automatically zip it then you are getting into customizing the build template like the others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to customize the workflow as you expect you can see the following link that describe step by step with images how to customize the folder in the build

http://lajak.wordpress.com/2011/05/07/customize-binaries-folder-in-tfs-team-build/

Thanks

M.Radwan

Comment: hi, sorry i didn't mention that the project is a PHP project, made with VS.PHP so i don't need any of the solution / workspace / compile things..., it would be great if i knew how to execute a batch script on the TFS ? I will need a click by click guide.., thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to execute a script on the TFS server there are different ways of doing so:

1. Go to the machine that is running the TFS server
2. Get access to a command prompt.
3. Run your script.

The above can also be run remotely via various tools or remote desktop.

If you want to automate a script to run on the TFS Server, there are a bunch of options as well. You can for instance us AT to schedule a batch job (*.BAT or *.CMD) to run on specific times.

if you want a deployment script to run when you check stuff into the TFS or when you "build" you need to use MS workflow foundation. It is called a "build" even if you are not actually compiling anything. These build scripts have a standard format, which will include compile steps as real programming languages have those. You can safely ignore those steps, just let them stay there.

Go under Builds in the TFS entry for your project in TFS (or website I guess?). Clone one of the existing builds and make a new one. Make a new XAML file for your PHP deployment process as well, cause otherwise you will destroy the normal build if other people are using your TFS for other things. In the build process XAML, make the changes as described in the answers above. In the property dialog for your build, (two separate words here, "build", you can have many of those that follow the same "build process". You could use the same process to deploy many different PHP sites, where things like the target folder will be supplied in the "Process" tab in the Property pages for your various Builds), under Trigger, set it as Continuous Integration, which means this new build of yours with this new custom build process of yours will run every time you check in.

BAM there you go.